# Read data from columns in .xlsx and save each one as seperate .txt file with python

Tags: python, excel

I need to make a script in python to read one column at a time from .xlsx file and save data from each in new .txt file with conecutive names like (file1.txt, file2.txt...)
I alredy have some parts of script, but am unable to combine them.

part of script for selecting data:

```
for i in range(1, m_row + 1):
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=j+1)
    print(cell_obj.value)
    print(cell_obj.value, file=open(
        file.txt',
        'a'))
```

for naming file:

```
while i: 
    i+=1
    try:
        with open('output{}.txt'.format(i), 'x'): 
    break
    except PermissionError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

this script works. The key is indenting second for statement

```
import openpyxl
path = "input.xlsm"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
m_row = sheet_obj.max_row
m_col = sheet_obj.max_column

for j in range(1, m_col + 1):
    name = sheet_obj.cell(row=2200, column=j).value
    outputFile = open(r'file.{}.txt'.format(name), 'w')
    for i in range(1, m_row + 1):
        cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=j)
        print(cell_obj.value, file=outputFile)
    outputFile.close()
```